AWS Managed Service
How does AWS Managed Services (AMS) play nicely with third-party monitoring and management tools that our team might already be using? We have some established systems in place, and I’m curious about how AMS can fit into that puzzle. Will it easily integrate with tools like Datadog, Splunk, or New Relic, and how smooth is that process?

Do you have a specific role you think it will fit? This question seems very broad and generally opinion-seeking. Could you focus it perhaps by providing some more information about the research you have done and things you hope to accomplish by it, or even better, what you've tried so far?
